# Edit line thickness of CSS 'underline' attribute

Tags: html, css

Since you can underline any text in CSS like so:

```css
h4 {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

How can you also then edit the 'line' that is drawn, the color you get on the line is easily specified as `color: red` but how does one edit the height of the line, i.e. the thickness?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Here is one way of achieving this :

HTML :

```
<h4>This is a heading</h4>

<h4><u>This is another heading</u></h4>
```

​CSS :

```css
u {
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}​
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/AQ9rL/

Comment: ...or multiple lines of text

Comment: In that case you have to wrap the text from each line, before and after the line-break with `<span>` and apply the border-bottom in there. It's a workaround that could be painful in non-hardcoded scenarios though.

Comment: @cfx if you can, you can still do this with `display: inline;` (but it would no longer be block of any kind then, could help somebody though)

Comment: This will cause the layout to change. A border will force other elements to move, unlike an underscore which will not.

Answer (score 58):

Recently I had to deal with FF which underlines were too thick and too far from the text in FF, and found a better way to deal with it using a pair of box-shadows:

```css
.custom-underline{
  box-shadow: inset 0 0px 0 white, inset 0 -1px 0 black
}
```

First shadow is put on top of the second one and that's how you can control the second one by varying the 'px' value of both.

Plus: various colors, thickness and underline position

Minus: can not use on non-solid backgrounds

Here I made couple of examples:
http://jsfiddle.net/xsL6rktx/

Comment: How neat. A pro (to me atleast) for this one in respect to border-bottom is that the "line" thickness grows towards the text, which makes the gap between text and line less huge.

Comment: I get half pixel vertical lines in addition to the underline when doing this.

Comment: Seems like it was at one point a perfect answer, but I get very very thin vertical lines on each side of the element in Chrome 66

Comment: Instead of **white**, using __transparent__ would work in case of any background.

Comment: This is best answer. There's no need to alter the HTML and pure CSS solution which won't alter positions like what borders do.

Comment: please remember box-shadow is cpu intensive

Answer (score 24):

There is `text-decoration-thickness`, currently part of [CSS Text Decoration Module Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-decor-4/#text-decoration-width-property). It's at "Editor's Draft" stage - so it's a **work in progress** and subject to change. As of October 2022, [it has about 93% coverage](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_properties_text-decoration-thickness) so it's pretty safe to use.

> The text-decoration-thickness CSS property sets the thickness, or
> width, of the decoration line that is used on text in an element, such
> as a line-through, underline, or overline.

```css
a {
  text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/mrotaru/pen/yLyLOgr (Firefox only)

---

There's also `text-decoration-color`, which is part of [CSS Text Decoration Module Level 3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-decor-3/#text-decoration-color-property). This is more mature (Candidate Recommendation) and is supported in most major browsers (exceptions are Edge and IE). Of course it can't be used to alter the thickness of the line, but can be used to achieve a more "muted" underline (also shown in the codepen).

Comment: If the user is on Firefox, all the text decoration things can be accessed in [`text-decoration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration). I don't know if this is planned to be included in all of them, but if so it will be very nice in the future. EDIT: [it is a working draft to support this in `text-decoration`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-decor-4/).

Comment: interesting but doesnt really work in a lot of browsers as of now https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-decoration-thickness/#browser-support

Answer (score 18):

Very easy ... outside "span" element with small font and underline, and inside "font" element with bigger font size.

```html
<span style="font-size:1em;text-decoration:underline;">
 <span style="font-size:1.5em;">
   Text with big font size and thin underline
 </span>
</span>
```

Comment: If you replace the obsolete `<font>` tag with a `span` tag, this would be the only answer that actually addresses the question.

Answer (score 12):

Another way to do this is using ":after" (pseudo-element) on the element you want to underline.

```css
h2 {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  font-weight:700;
  font-family:arial,sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-size:3em;
}
h2:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  margin:auto;
  background:#000;
  height:1px;
}
```

Comment: similar answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23502743/5091805

Answer (score 11):

**I will do something simple like :**

```css
.thickness-underline {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

- You can use `line-height` or `padding-bottom` to set possition between them
- You can use `display: inline` in some case

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/5580pqe8/

[image: CSS underline]

Comment: Unfortunately, margin-bottom cannot get negative values.

Comment: @soleshoe That's incorrect, you can have negative margin on the bottom of an element.

Answer (score 9):

The `background-image` can also be used to create an underline. This method handles line breaks.

It has to be shifted down via `background-position` and repeated horizontally. The line width can be adjusted to some degree using `background-size` (the background is limited to the content box of the element).

```css
.underline
{
    --color: green;
    font-size: 40px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(var(--color) 0%, var(--color) 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0 1.05em;
    background-size: 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<span class="underline">
     Underlined<br/>
     Text
</span>
```

Comment: You can also animate that as well. Which is nice.

Answer (score 7):

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
}

a.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a.shadow {
   box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 0 white, inset 0 -4.5px 0 blue;
}
```

```html
<h1><a href="#" class="underline">Default: some text alpha gamma<br>the quick brown fox</a></h1>
<p>Working:</p>
<h1><a href="#" class="shadow">Using Shadow: some text alpha gamma<br>the quick brown fox<br>even works with<br>multiple lines</a></h1>
<br>
```

Final Solution: 
http://codepen.io/vikrant-icd/pen/gwNqoM

```
a.shadow {
   box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 0 white, inset 0 -4.5px 0 blue;
}
```

Comment: Issue is underline is rendered by different browsers differently.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to the magic of new [css options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration) this is now possible natively:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-thickness: 5px;
  text-decoration-skip-ink: auto;
  text-underline-offset: 3px;
}
```

As of yet support is relatively [poor](https://caniuse.com/#search=text-decoration-thickness). But it'll land in other browsers than ff eventually.

Answer (score 4):

My Solution :
https://codepen.io/SOLESHOE/pen/QqJXYj

```
{
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 70%;
}
```

You can adjust underline position with line-height value, underline thickness and style with border-bottom.

Beware to disable default underline behavior if you want to underline an href.

Answer (score 0):

Now, as can be seen in the picture below, the property is fully supported in most browsers (according to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-thickness)).

[image]

So, you can use the following attributes:

```css
.thin {
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
  text-decoration-color: red;
  text-decoration-thickness: 1px;
}

.thick {
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-style: solid;
  text-decoration-color: red;
  text-decoration-thickness: 5px;
}

.shorthand {
  text-decoration: underline solid red 5px;
}
```

(example code from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-thickness)).