# CSS underline less than width of headline?

Tags: css, underline

Is it possible with CSS to make the underline of a headline less wide than the headline text? I have the following style for an H1 headline:

```
h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px #d2202f solid;
}
```

This produces a thin red underline below my H1 headlines. However, is it possible to make it so that the underline is 50% of the text in the headline?

Comment: Sorry, I searched several phrases and didn't find anything similar.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element with `:before` (or `:after`):

```
h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
h1:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 1px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 25%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9e27b/

Comment: Not working with multiple lines of text...

Comment: For multiline:
    content: '';
    bottom: 0;
    left: 30%;
    right: 30%;
    height: 2px;
    background: red;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    position: static;
    margin-left: 25%;

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no.

Normal borders cannot do this, but you can fake it with a CSS3 gradient border.

See: [CSS3 Gradient Borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/css3-gradient-borders)

Comment: Please improve the answer quality a little bit, maybe with some example. I cannot vote for deletion as it is not bad enough, but it is not good enough aswell.