# Setting Underline Thickness in CSS

Tags: css, border, underline, thickness

I'm redesigning my website and wish to have certain paragraphs styled like in the below image.

[image]

I thought this would be fine but now it's suddenly just hit me... there's no way to set the thickness of an underline! Or at least I don't think there is?

Of course there is the border property, but then I would only have a border at the bottom of the whole paragraph and not under each line.

Can anyone think of a workaround for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Edit line thickness of CSS 'underline' attibute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840403/edit-line-thickness-of-css-underline-attibute)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn your paragraph into an `inline` display: **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yFcaj)**

This way you can even set a `border-style` to your `underline`'like:

```
p {
  display:inline;
  border-bottom:3px double;
}
```

**[Single `<p>`aragraphs in between title](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmgBb)**

Comment: works nicely thanks! Unfortunately there seems to be gaps in between my sentences, but maybe I can work around it or simply live with it!

Comment: do you mean in between p ? if so , do the code like this: <p>sentence1</p><p>sentence2 glued to 1</p>

Comment: ahh sorry I didn't realise you had uploaded a demo! I did a quick test in Firebug last night and there were little gaps in between sentences (not p's). Maybe that was just some of the other styles I had going on though so I'll have another tinker about ;)

Answer (score 0):

An example of this would be:

h4 {border-bottom: 10px solid #000;}

I found this from another stack exchange question found here:
[Edit line thickness of CSS 'underline' attibute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840403/edit-line-thickness-of-css-underline-attibute)

Comment: In the future, if one question is a duplicate of another, please flag it as a duplicate instead of answering it.

Comment: @KatieK, from the looks of things, this is the first post of the user you are talking to. Perhaps cut them some slack as they would not know the rules.

Comment: @MathewMacLean - Yes, I realize they are new; that's why I provided feedback and handled the flagging. What specifically would you have done differently?

Comment: @KatieK the solution on that thread you've linked to would leave a border at the bottom of the paragraph only, whereas I need it under each line (as stated in my original message)