# Is there any way to add weight to a text-underline in css?

Tags: css, text-decorations

I have this code and I want to add weight to my curvy text-underline since it is too thin to actually have a visible impact. I've read about using border-bottom to add weight, but then I would not be able to make it curvy. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

```
.underline-yellow{
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: #FFBE00;
  text-decoration-style: wavy;
  padding-bottom:2px;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: Maybe using a background image? See the H.B. answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840403/edit-line-thickness-of-css-underline-attibute) SO question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way set a text underline thickness without changing the font properties.

You can play with `background-image` and make a kind of wavy style.

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
}
.underline-yellow{
  color: black;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 65%, yellow 80%, transparent 90%), linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 5%, yellow 15%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 45%, yellow 55%, transparent 65%), linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 25%, yellow 35%, transparent 50%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-size: 20px 5px;
    background-position: 0 100%;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
 }
```

```html
<span class="underline-yellow">My decorated text</span>
```

Comment: Glad its works. Please, read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
.underline-yellow{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 0px 1px 0 #f7eb9a;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0), 0px 1px 0 #f7eb9a;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.